# Finding moment-generating function and variance of discrete RV

Tags: probability, statistics

For the probability density function $p(y)=(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})^y, \ \ \ y=0,1,2,3....$, I'm trying to find the moment generating function (mgf) and variance.

Firstly, for the variance, would it just be calculated as $E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2$, i.e. $\sum_y y^2*p(y) - (\sum_y y*p(y))^2$ ?

Secondly, so far for finding the mgf I have:

$m(t)=E(e^{tY})$

$=\sum_y e^{ty}(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})^y$

$=(\frac{1}{2})\sum_y((\frac{e^t}{2})^y)$

I'm unsure of where to go from here, could someone please help me out?

Comment: Your expression for the mgf is an infinite geometric progression, the closed form for the sum is familiar.

Comment: Just look up the mgf for a Geometric random variable, defined on $0, 1, 2 ...$

Answer (score 0):

The comments pretty much nail your question, but here it is written out.  The MGF is 
$$M_y(t)={1\over 2}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}e^{ty}\left({1\over 2}\right)^{y}={1\over 2}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\left({1\over 2}e^{t}\right)^{y}$$
We know for $p\lt 1$ that $\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}p^{y}={1 \over 1-p}$, so naturally
$$M_y(t)={1\over 2}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\left({1\over 2}e^{t}\right)^{y}={1\over 2}\left({1 \over 1-\left({1\over 2}e^{t}\right)}\right)={1\over 2-e^t}$$
As to finding the variance, you are correct to use $E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2$, though now that you have the MGF you can use it to find them instead of evaluating a sum.

$$E[Y]=M_y(t)'\mid_{t=0}={e^t\over (2-e^t)^2}\mid_{t=0}=1$$
$$E[Y^2]=M_y(t)''\mid_{t=0}={2e^{2t} \over (2-e^t)^3}+{e^t\over (2-e^t)^2}\mid_{t=0}=3$$
So $Var(Y)=3-1^2=2$.